# Doubts in backtracking function animation, for call sequence flow

Tags: compilers, backtracking

In the slides' based  animation given for backtracking, [here](https://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/lsa/lectures/backtrack.pdf) (with code [here](https://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/lsa/lectures/backtrack.c), in the [web-page](https://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/lsa/)
); have few doubts, in the code restated below, and the execution as shown in the call #5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *next;
int calls = 0;

int eat(char c) {
  calls++;
  if (*next == c) {
    next++;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
  
int e() {   
    char* save = next;    
    if(eat('(')&&e()&& 
    eat('+')&&e()&&eat(')')) 
        return 1;   
    else next = save;    
    if(eat('(')&&e()&&eat('*') 
    && e()&&eat (')'))  
        return 1;   
    else next = save;    
    if (v()) 
        return 1;   
    else 
        next = save;    
    return 0; 
}
int v() {
    char* save = next;
    calls++;

    if (eat('x')) return 1;
    else next = save;

    if (eat('y')) return 1;
    else next = save;

    return 0;
}

void main()
{
  next = "((((x*x)*x)*x)*x)";
  printf("%i\n", e());
  printf("%i\n", calls);
}
```

Request correction, and comments, for my analysis, and doubts, below:

1. In the code, the two operators, i.e. '+', '*'; are of equal precedence. Though, am confused if am correct in describing the grammar for the code.

*e -> (e + e) | (e * e) | v*

*v -> **x** | **y***

2. For the call #5, unable to understand how the execution flow jumped to the the second *if* statement, though tried multiple times to figure out the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a few minutes to figure out what functions $e()$ and $v()$ do but after some careful reading I got to the conclusion they implement a recursive descent parser whose language $\mathcal{L}$ is the one made of arithmetic expressions on identifiers $x$ and $y$.

Regarding your first question, I don't think operators $*$ and $+$ share the same precedence; the language accepted by the parser corresponds to arithmetic expressions having fully specified parenthesis (adding numbers to the language matched by $v()$, "$1+2*3$" is clearly not in $\mathcal{L}$, while "$(1+(2*3))$" is). To my understanding $e()$ implements the rules of regular arithmetic, that is, $*$'s precedence is greater that $+$'s. I reached this conclusion observing that missing parenthesis are not allowed and precedence is not enforced by the parser but rather by properly nested parens.
Consequently, a bottom-up grammar generating this kind of precedence is $\mathcal{G}$:

- $E \rightarrow E + T \text{ }|\text{ } T$
- $T \rightarrow T * F \text{ }|\text{ } F$
- $F \rightarrow (E) \text{ }|\text{ } num$

(with some adjustments you can easily get the LL1, that is top-down, version.)

Regarding your second question, the parser (via call 4) first tries to consume a sequence of characters of the shape $( \text{ } E \text{ } + \text{ } E \text{ })$ (but fails because no parenthesis is present), then (via call 5) it tries to consume $(\text{ }E \text{ }*\text{ }E\text{ })$ failing for the same reason. Eventually, it will try to consume $x$ via function $v()$ in call 6, with success.

I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please see my post at: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/161359/78009.